# Scale Colors in a Multi Barplot by Column Value

Tags: python, colors, plotly, bar-chart

From a multiple groups barplot, I would like each bar to take a different color within a continuous scale according to an extra column in the dataset.
For example, from the next plot, each bar would have an color intensity according to an extra dataset continuos column. [image]

Comment: Might be useful if you include some sample data and code to produce the above plot.

Comment: If you give a numerical list for the marker color settings, it will automatically be color-coded in a continuous color map. `marker_color=[20, 14, 25, 16, 18, 22, 19, 15, 12, 16, 14, 17]` The same setting can be given for the next category. However, there is a discrepancy. The same value will produce bars with different colors.